# How to manipulate Spacebars when an object property uses colon in its writing?

Tags: meteor, spacebars

I'm trying to learn how to work with meteor and google analytics API.

I had a problem with the syntax of the spacebars...

When I try to access an object everything works well...like this:

**HTML** - Using space bars double brackets to access an atribute of an object inside another object:

```
    {{# each performanceRow}}
            <tr>
                <td class="choiceId {{selectedChoice}}">{{name}}</td>
                <td class="choiceId {{selectedChoice}}">{{indicator}}</td>
                <td class="choiceId {{selectedChoice}}">{{goal}}</td>
                <td class="choiceId {{selectedChoice}}">             {{current.profileInfo.profileId}}</td>
            </tr>
   {{/each}}
```

The problem happens because one of the attributes is written as `follow: ga:exitRate`

And then, if I try to reproduce it with space-bars meteor doesn't recognize the colon as the name of the field. As follows:

```
{{current.totalsForAllResults.ga:exitRate}}
```

How can I contour this situation?

Comment: is there a possibility to rename the field to ga_exitRate?

Comment: have you tried creating a helper for it to return the desired value only instead?

Comment: Agree with Luna, a helper that refers to `this`, placed within `{{totalsForAllResults}}`, and returning `this['ga:exitRate']` should work.

Comment: Thank you @Ankit, @Luna and @RishatMuhametshin.

ga_exitRate didn't worked.

I haven't tried the approach shared by @Luna and @RishatMuhametshin, but using `{{ [current.totalsForAllResults.ga:exitRate] }}`, made the trick for me.

Sorry for my mistakes in the edition of the question. Still learning how to work with stackoverflow. Thank you for correcting it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [guide](https://docs.meteor.com/packages/spacebars.html#Identifiers-and-Paths): A Spacebars identifier is either a JavaScript identifier name or any string enclosed in square brackets ([ what a nice string ]). As such, I presume you can just use it like this:

```
{{ [current.totalsForAllResults.ga:exitRate] }}
```

I haven't tried with nested objects yet, but I know for sure that it works with identifiers that have a space in it, so e.g. this works

```
{{ [custom field] }}
```

when you would access it from javascript like this

```
doc['custom field']
```

Let me know it works.

Comment: Good catch! :-) I would have thought that only the identifier would be in square brackets, while the path would be as usual? Then it is very similar to JS access, except for extraneous dot or slash as separator, and no need for quotes: `current.totalsForAllResults.[ga:exitRate]` (see the last part of the guid section you refer to)

Comment: I don't think so. For me it looks like you either use a string in brackets or js identifier. Did you test it?

Comment: I have not tested, but then how could it determine whether `[path.to.my field]` means `path.to["my field"]` or `["path.to.my field"]`? (even though of course the 2nd one would be horrible practice, but legal).

Comment: Beware that the string in the brackets is not enclosed in `"`! Everything you write in the brackets is interpreted as a string. So your second example would be `[path.to.my field]`. Pretty sure that works just fine.

Comment: I meant: does _spacebars_ `{{[path.to.my field]}}` means _JavaScript_ `path.to["my field"]` or _JavaScript_ `["path.to.my field"]`. Test shows that _spacebars_ `{{[current.totalsForAllResults.ga:exitRate]}}` means _JavaScript_ `["current.totalsForAllResults.ga:exitRate"]`, whereas you need to write _spacebars_ `{{current.totalsForAllResults.[ga:exitRate]}}` to get _JavaScript_ `current.totalsForAllResults["ga:exitRate"]`

Comment: First of all, thank you @tomsp and @ghybs.

I had success with this approach:
`{{current.totalsForAllResults.[ga:exitRate]}}` .

Like pointed by @ghybs, this notation works to get Javascript. Its very usefull for when you have colons, space and etc in your object, and you want to access it with spacebars.

However this one didn't worked for me:
`{{ [current.totalsForAllResults.ga:exitRate] }}` .

When I have tried this second approach the values of the objects become hidden on the browser.

Comment: Cool, thanks @ghybs and Minatogawa. Learned something today :)